# is there a way to know how much RAM a session use?

Tags: asp.net, session

I got in a session a class with type-safe variable; int, string, dataset, etc

is there a way to find out how much memory is used by that session?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a profiler is your best bet. Personally I really like jetbrains [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).